# NodeJS to Postman Result

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Good Day how can i compute a public function to route and check it on Postman? here is my codes

```
router.post('/post_regular_hours/:employee_id/',function(request,response,next){
    var id = request.params.employee_id;
    var time_in = request.params.time_in;
    var time_out = request.params.time_out;
    // const timein = request.params.time_in;
    // const timeout = request.params.time_out;
    knexDb.select('*')
            .from('employee_attendance')
            .where('employee_id',id)
            .then(function(result){

                res.send(compute_normal_hours(response,result,diff))


            })
});

function compute_normal_hours(res,result,diff){

    let time_in = moment(time_in);
    let time_out = moment(time_out);


    let diff = time_out.diff(time_in, 'hours');



    return diff;

}
```

I want the Diff to get posted on Postman as a result
Here is the App.js of my codes. How can i  call the data from mysql query to the function and return the computed data on router post
or can you guys give the right terminologies for it.

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql= require('mysql');
var employee = require('./routes/employee');
var time_record = require('./routes/time_record');
var admin_employee = require('./routes/admin_employee');
var tar = require('./routes/tar');
var Joi = require('joi');

var app = express();



app.get('/hello',function(req,res){
  var name = "World";
  var schema = {
      name: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required()
  };
  var result = Joi.validate({ name : req.query.name }, schema);
  if(result.error === null)
  {
     if(req.query.name && req.query.name != '')
    {
      name = req.query.name;
    }
    res.json({
      "message" : "Hello "+name + "!"
    });
  }
  else
  {
    res.json({
      "message" : "Error"
    });
  }

}); 


//Database connection
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    global.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'locahost',
        user     : 'dbm_project',
      password : 'dbm1234',
        database : 'dbm_db'
    });
    connection.connect();
    next();
});

app.use('/', employee);
app.use('/employee', time_record);
app.use('/admin', admin_employee);
app.use('/tar', tar);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.listen(8000,function(){
  console.log("App started on port 8000!");
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the App.js of my codes. How can i  call the data from mysql query to the function and return the computed data on router po

Comment: What do you mean by you want this to get posted on Postman? You mean you want to check with postman through a post request?

Comment: yes sir, i need to get the data and check it on postman

Comment: Have you tried a post request from postman already? What's not working?

Comment: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. this is the error sir

Comment: can you add your app.js code as well please, where you consume this router?

Comment: Did you generate your server code using express-generator?

Comment: var tar = require('./routes/tar'); and app.use('/tar', tar); is in my app,js

Comment: Which I'm assuming this route is in one of those files?

Comment: yea all i need is the computation of the data on function then i must see it on postman

Comment: Did you set a view engine? in your app.js?

Comment: Are you using a module / function called diff?

Comment: i really dont need the view engine, but there is no view engine in my app.js

Comment: Are you calling res.render in any place?

Comment: nope, i know render is to pass the data to a page right?

Comment: is the diff you're passing as a parameter a function?

Comment: Can you please fix the compute_normal_hours function? You are passing parameters that you're not using / response or result is unused and naming of the variables is all over the place.

Comment: can you give me example?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.
Please see explanations in the respective code chunks.

```
router.post('/post_regular_hours/:employee_id/',function(request,response,next){

    // If you're receiving a post request
    // you'll probably want to check the body for these parameters.
    let id = request.params.employee_id; // make sure the param names are matching with what you post.
    // This one is special because you are passing it through the url directly
    let time_in = request.body.time_in;
    let time_out = request.body.time_out;        

    knexDb.select('*')
            .from('employee_attendance')
            .where('employee_id',id)
            .then(function(result){

                // you are not sending time_in and time_out here - but difference. but difference is not calculated.
                // changed the function signature a bit - you weren't using the result at all? leaving this callback here because I'm sure you want to map the used time to some user?
                return response.send(compute_normal_hours(time_in, time_out))
            });
});

// this function was (and still might be) incorrect.
// You were passing res and result which neither of them you were using.
// You also had time_in and time_out which were going to be undefined in the function scope. Now that we are passing them in it should be ok. Updated it so you don't have the params you don't need.

function compute_normal_hours(time_in, time_out){
    // What was diff - if it's the time difference name things correctly
    // You had a diff parameter passed in (which you didn't compute), a diff function called below and another variable declaration called diff.
    // you were not passing time_in or time_out parameters.
    // you have moment here - are you using a library?
    let time_in = moment(time_in);
    let time_out = moment(time_out);

    let diff = time_out.diff(time_in, 'hours');

    return `Computed result is: ${diff}`;    
}
```

**Important Edit**

Please search for all occurences of res.render (response.render) and replace them with something like res.send - res.render is looking for the template engine

Comment: not working but i tried it on template engine to test the formula and its working, but i need it directly without posting it on template engines

Comment: Can you please share your app.js code that would make things so much easier

Comment: @ByronMataya is `tar` the name of the file which you have this computing logic in?

Comment: @ByronMataya have you verified your DB connection to be working?

Comment: yes when i get the employee_id to get all data as result, and making it JSON.stringify(result), it shows all data of the specific ID

Comment: Please add app.use(bodyParser.json()); after you do var app = express();

Comment: Also edited my code - looks like you are passing the employee id through the url, that's probably read differently.

Comment: You said you didn't have res.render in your code! You have it in your error handler! (In app.js) **Please search for all occurences of res.render and replace them with something like res.send - res.render is looking for the template engine!**

Comment: @ByronMataya let me know if that solves it. I think you'll get some other error, but this problem should be solved after you replaced all res.render's

Comment: its still looking for template engine mate,

Comment: Did you clear all of the render functions? In **all of the routes, everywhere in your code**

Comment: Check your employee / time record / admin routes